# C# - Printing a matrix, and updating it with new data

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# in highschool at the moment. I'm a beginner, and I'm trying to do the following:

I have a task where I need to print a matrix, and update it using cases.

First, I created a simple matrix that prints -1 on a 20 on 5 square:

```
bankMatrix = new int[20, 5];
for (int i = 0; i < bankMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < bankMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0,3}", bankMatrix[i, j] = -1);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Which outputs the following:

```
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Next, the user chooses a column from 1-5 via a case statement.
What I'd like to see is the program updates the first `-1` it finds in the selected column to `0`, and print the matrix with the change the next time I call it.

For example, if the user selects 4, it should look like this:

```
 -1 -1 -1  0 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

I tried the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("please choose where would you like to create your account (we have 5 branches, choose one):");
int accountBranch = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
accountBranch = accountBranch - 1;
bool branch = false;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < bankMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    if (bankMatrix[i, accountBranch] == -1)
    {
        branch = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (branch)
{
    bankMatrix[i, accountBranch] = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("account saved");
    Console.WriteLine("the bank situation (-1 = un-occupied place for an account in branches, 0 = occupied place)");
    for (i = 0; i < bankMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bankMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0,3}", bankMatrix[i, accountBranch] = 0);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Which does two things wrong:

- It sets the whole matrix to 0
- It prints the matrix again - which I only want to do when I call the matrix function.

I'm not sure how to approach this. What would be the best (simple) way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually very close to the solution. You got two mistakes:

1. Instead of setting your element in the matrix to zero you just need to print it.
2. You need to print the element at [i , j] instead of element at [i , accountBranch]

So here is the corrected version of your code :

```
                for (int j = 0; j < bankMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,3}", bankMatrix[i, j]);
                }
```

Comment: You are wellcome. Can you accept it as answer, if it solves your problem? Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Thanks! :D